# Why does IntelliJ override each method by default when programatically implementing method stubs?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Just curious if anyone knows the reason. I'm new to Scala so I figure it's something obvious to a seasoned Scalaroo, and I oughtn't bug JetBrains about it.

Comment: Can you show an example? Are you sure it's not doing it only for abstract methods (e.g. in traits)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch this behaviour off. Just uncheck the "Add override modifier" field at the bottom of the "Select Members to Implement" dialog. IntelliJ IDEA will remember this setting.